# Trouble Writing Array

Tags: java

I'm attempting to write an array. Its description is best described by this:

> Each day a fisherman will weigh in at most 10 fish, the weight of which you are required to store in an array of double values.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class DailyCatch
{
    private int fishermanID, fisherID;
    private String dateOfSample, date;
    private double[] weights;
    private double[] fishCaught = new double[10];
    private int currWeight = 0;

public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample, String weightsAsString)
{
    fisherID = fishermanID;
    date = dateOfSample;
    // Parse the the weigths string and store the list of weights in this array.
    weights = readWeights(weightsAsString);
}

 public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample)
 {
    fisherID = fishermanID;
    date = dateOfSample;
 }

 public void addFish(double weight)
 {
    if (currWeight > 10)
    {
     // array full
 }
    else
{
  fishCaught[currWeight] = weight;
  currWeight += 1;  // update current index of array
    }
 }

private double[] readWeights(String weightsAsString) 
{
    String[] weightsArr = weightsAsString.split("\\s+");
    double[] weights = new double[weightsArr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i <  weights.length; i++) {
        double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightsArr[i]);
    }
    return weights;
}

 public void printWeights()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
  {
    System.out.println(fishCaught[i]);
    } 
 }

public String toString()
{
    return "Fisherman ID: " + fisherID + "\nDate: " + date + "\nWeights: " + Arrays.toString(weights);
}
```

}

This is the test file I'm working with on this project:

```
public class BigBass
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
DailyCatch monday1 = new DailyCatch(32, "4/1/2013", "4.1 5.5 2.3 0.5 4.8 1.5");
System.out.println(monday1);

DailyCatch monday2 = new DailyCatch(44, "4/1/2013");
monday2.addFish(2.1);
monday2.addFish(4.2);
System.out.println(monday2);
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, you need a default constructor. And it seems to me that you just define an array for fish.

Comment: Yes. But it gives me an error when I do saying it requires a double and it finds a string.

Comment: Teach a man to allocate an array of double values for his fish, and he'll be fed for a lifetime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the overloaded constructors to reduce code duplication. Constructors are able to call themselves, which comes hand when multiple constructors are setting the same member variables.

I added the addFish method (as shown in your test) that simply adds the weight to the array based on the current index of the array (which starts at 0). Whenever a new fish weight is added, the currWeight is incremented so that the next fish can be added at the next index.

The readWeights method parses the passed string into tokens that are delimited by a space. Each token is put into the class's fishCaught array be using the addFish method.

```
public class DailyCatch
{
  private int fishermanID, fisherID;
  private String dateOfSample, date;
  private double[] fishCaught = new double[10];
  private int currWeight = 0;

  public DailyCatch() {  }

  public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample)
  {
    fisherID = fishermanID;
    date = dateOfSample;
  }

  public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample, String weight)
  {
    this(fishermanID, dateOfSample);
    readWeights(weight);
  }

  public void addFish(double weight)
  {
    if (currWeight > 10)
    {
       // array full
    }
    else
    {
      fishCaught[currWeight] = weight;
      currWeight += 1;  // update current index of array
    }
  }

  private void readWeights(String weightsAsString) 
  {
    String[] weightsRead = weightsAsString.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < weightsRead.length; i++) 
    {
       this.addFish(Double.parseDouble(weightsRead[i]));
    }
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "Fisherman ID: " + fisherID + "\nDate:" + date + "\nWeights: " + Arrays.toString(fishCaught);
  }

  public void printWeights()
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
     {
          System.out.println(fishCaught[i]);
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have any idea why I'm unable to print the array?

Comment: @DevonFreese do you want to print it from within the class or outside of it?

Comment: I wanted to print it using that toString in there. But I got that working. However, instead of printing the weights declared, it prints out just "0.0".

Comment: @DevonFreese I added a printWeights method (see above). How are you printing? can you paste how you're calling the code? It will either print 0 because you're creating a new DailyCatch object when trying to print (which will have an empty array) or the printing is wrong.

Comment: `public String toString(){return "Fisherman ID: " + fisherID + "\Date: " + date + \nWeights: " + Arrays.toString(weights);`

Comment: print out the length of the weights array.. what is it? edit: try the printWeights method I added too

Comment: So when I try printing the length of the array I get an error saying "cannot find symbol". And when I use your method, it doesn't even display. Very strange.

Comment: Can you update your question to your current code and the code you're using to call everything.

Comment: Updated. This code incorporates your code and the first answer as well. If that's a problem, I can change to yours.

Comment: @DevonFreese you're trying to combine answers.. have you tried just my code? try it w. your calling code to see if it works.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. Secondly, I had to remove `this.addFish` because it was throwing an error. Anyhow, after doing that it still prints zeros instead of number.

Comment: What error was is throwing? What print are you using? if it's not printing anything, it seems as if nothing is getting added to the array.

Comment: This was the error: " error: not a statement". And this is what printed: "Fisherman ID: 32
Date:4/1/2013
Weights: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Fisherman ID: 44
Date:4/1/2013
Weights: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"

Comment: @DevonFreese I got it working. See update (i just tested it out).

Comment: Can we move this to a chat? I copied this exactly and still it doesn't do what it should.

Comment: I don't think you can get into a chat. I'm willing to help though

Comment: Thanks. It just still prints the zeros. But for the addFish part it does add the two numbers to the array.

Comment: what's your email? we can chat there

Comment: I have a few accounts. Would you rather yahoo or gmail?

Comment: oh shoot..... [at]severelabs.com.....sorry

Comment: wait, so what is it? freeze [at] severelabs.com?

Comment: yes that's it. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DailyCatch
{
    private int fishermanID, fisherID;
    private String dateOfSample, date;
    private double[] weights;

    public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample, String weightsAsString)
    {
        fisherID = fishermanID;
        date = dateOfSample;
        // Parse the string and store the list of weights in this array.
        weights = readWeights(weightsAsString);
    }

    private double[] readWeights(String weightsAsString) 
    {
        String[] weightsArr = weightsAsString.split("\s+");
        double[] weights = new double[weightsArr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i <  weights.length; i++) {
            double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightsArr[i]);
        }
        return weights;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Fisherman ID: " + fisherID + "\nDate: " + date + "\nweights: " + Arrays.toString(weights);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this I get an error saying there is an illegal escape character having to do with "\s+"

Comment: I am certainly not upvoting this answer in *this* form. You just dump a bunch of code, not explaining what it does or how to use it.

Comment: @DevonFreese use `"\\s+"` instead

Comment: Thanks Doorknob. Now I get this: "DailyCatch.java:27: error: method parseDouble in class Double cannot be applied to given types;
         double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightsArr);
                               ^
  required: String
  found: String[]
  reason: actual argument String[] cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion" Never seen that before.

Comment: @DevonFreese: Now it should go: `Double.parseDouble(weightsArr[i]);`

Comment: @user278064: Thank you for that. My next problem is with the toString. When I want to print those weights I just get the ASCII values for the numbers.

Comment: @DevonFreese: Use `Arrays.toString(weights);`. I've modified the `toString()` code.

Comment: Okay I got it. Had to use "import java.util.*;" But the weights in the array all print out to "0.0". Argh this is frustrating.